# Spark Sql : Partition by hour_interval from timestamp

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have 4 fields in my dataset(SparkSql) and my aim is to extract hour from timestamp and then partition by hour_interval in spark.sql query

1. username(varchar)
2. timestamp(long)
3. ipaddress(varchar)

Now these are the things, i need to partition by hour_interval from the longtimestamp .

So i created a test table in mysql and I tried below command, it works for fetching hour _interval from timestamp

[image]

```
SELECT username, originaltime , ipaddress, HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(originaltime / 1000)) as hourinterval FROM testmyactivity ;
```

This gives below output

`suresasash3456 1557731954785   1.1.1.1 1   7`

Now I need to partition by this hour_interval but I am not able to do it

Below is the query which is not working

```
SELECT username, ipaddress , HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(originaltime / 1000)) as hourinterval, OVER (partition by hourinterval) FROM testmyactivity ;
```

The above gives me the error message

right syntax to use near 'partition by hour interval)

Expected Output
Step 1 :
Spark Sql query which can extract hour from the timestamp and then partition by hour_interval

Step2: After the above step,  i can perform groupByKey on hour_interval so that my dataset will be equally distributed to executors available

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing us clear sample input along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning) is the documentation.

```
val partitioned_df = df.partitionBy($"colName")
partitioned_df.explain
```

now you can use `partitioned_df` for group-by queries.